# Can I suppress UA validation of HTML5 "email" fields?

Tags: html, input, html-email

When using HTML5 "email" fields —  `<input type="email"/>` — a lot of UAs (user agents/browsers) prevent you from submitting the form without using a "valid" (by regex) email address.  They also apply the `:invalid` pseudoclass.  However this my conflict with your own validation scheme, and the lack of direct feedback may confusing visitors.  Also, :invalid is applied (in Chrome 8) to my field before anyone even attempts to submit it.  I hate this. I t makes it look like the user has made a mistake, but they haven’t yet.

So is it possible to use  `<input type="email"/>` without triggering validation behavior?

Comment: Not to sound sarcastic but isn't that just <input type="text" />. Why do you want to use this type if you don't want the inherit features it offers?

Comment: @spinon Not quite. UAs are free to improve  `<input type="email"/>` in other ways — Consider iOS devices. They actually use a different keyboard entirely, with `@` and `.` keys visible where parts of the spacebar would normally be, when the user is filling an email field.

Comment: yeah I was thinking about that after I wrote it. There is that feature that does it make it convenient for devices.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to Philip Taylor (`Philip`) on the irc.w3.org#html-wg IRC room:

> http://whatwg.org/html5#attr-fs-novalidate says you can use  to disable validation for the whole form

So basically, you can apply `novalidate` as an attribute on the entire form.  You can also specify a submit button to submit the form without validating — the canonical example is a “save progress” button that doesn’t validate at all.  In that case, you put `formnovalidate` on the submit button itself.

Comment: At least in Firefox, formnovalidate does prevent the bubble warning, but still adds a red validation error "glow" to the failed element.  To fix this use the :invalid pseudo-class (or the browser specific one) as outlined here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:invalid